# Is it possible to write a bash script that uses AWS policies and wires into Hipchat?

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I wrote an AWS IAM role policy that grants full ec2 and rds admin access based on a custom tag applied to instances. Is it possible to write a bash script that uses these policies to let developers run the ec2 and rds full admin API commands from an app like Hipchat? If this is possible, can you post an example script of how to get this started?

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem? Is there a specific part of this process you're having trouble with? We don't want to write your whole application for you... we want to help you with parts that you have trouble figuring out yourself.

Comment: Yes, getting started is the specific part of process I'm stuck on. I'm a newbie to bash scripting..Tieing in the IAM policies is a new challenge I'm taking on. I found this post that shows what I'm trying to accomplish seems to be possible in perl http://serverfault.com/questions/532675/which-permissions-policies-for-iam-role-to-be-used-with-cloudwatch-monitoring-sc, but I'd prefer to do this in Bash scripting.

Comment: Is your script going to run on an Amazon EC2 instance that has a role applied, which has the necessary permissions? Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: When you say that the policy "grants full ec2 and rds admin access based on a custom tag", do you mean that it APPLIES TO the instances (via an IAM role being applied to the EC2 instance), or simply allows API calls that IMPACT those instances (with the policy separately applied to a user/role)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes this is a role policy that'll apply to those ec2 and rds instances.

Comment: IAM Roles can be assigned to Amazon EC2 instances, but not Amazon RDS instances.

Comment: Taking out RDS, where would I start in creating a skeleton Bash script with the Iam ec2 role policy only?